# Scrape websites from a list, parse full text, save as txt file - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of websites in a csv file that I want to scrape the full visible text from and save as individual txt files.

I am able to scrape the websites right now, but they come down with full HTML code. I have a script (below) that will take out that code and give me the visible text, but I am having trouble with the final steps.

```
   import urllib.request
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from bs4.element import Comment

    df = pd.read_csv('~/ids.csv', sep = ',')
    df.head()

    def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


    def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

    for i in df.message_id:
        fp = urllib.request.urlretrieve('url='+str(i))
        l = text_from_html(fp) #<<<---ERROR HERE
        file = open(str(i)+".txt","w",encoding='utf-8')
        file.close()
        file.write(l)
```

I am getting a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. Apologies for what is probably a basic question.

Comment: Althought not related to your problem, I noticed you close your file before you write to it in `text_from_html()`.

Comment: I realized that I left a ) out of the code, thanks to those who commented. However, I am still getting an error. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Can you provide a sample (e.g. top 10 rows & column names) of what's in `ids.csv`?

Comment: and what URL are you trying to read from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took awhile, but the code that works is below. Note that the urls.csv file contains one column with the header 'urls'.

```
import os
import requests
import urllib.request
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_csv('/urls.csv', sep = ',')
df.head()

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

for i in df.urls:
        fp = urllib.request.urlopen(i).read()
        l = text_from_html(fp)
        s = i[60:]
        file = open(str(s)+".txt","w",encoding='utf-8')
        file.write(l)
        file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a bracket.

```
fp = urllib.request.urlretrieve('url='+str(i))
                                             ^
```

Comment: Thank you, that was actually a typo. I have updated the question.